# jQuery fade in and out on timeout

Tags: jquery, timeout

This is a pretty common problem, but I am looking to fade out some text, change it then fade it back in.

My code so far is:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $("#ilovequote").fadeOut( 500, function(){
     var ilovequotes = ["CSS3", "Photoshop", "AJAX", "jQuery", "Social Media API's"];
    var rand = ilovequotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * ilovequotes.length)];
    $('#ilovequote').html(rand);
        $("#ilovequote").fadeIn( 500);
    });
  }, 500);
});
```

But this for some reason does not work. I am looking for help on this, basically I would like a smooth animation with just long enough to read the word.

JS FIDDLE

http://jsfiddle.net/rJDWb/

Comment: seems to work:: http://jsfiddle.net/BMBDd/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

```
var cnt = 0;
setInterval(function(){
cnt ==4 ? cnt=0:cnt++
    $("#ilovequote").fadeOut( 500, function(){
        var ilovequotes = ["CSS3", "Photoshop", "AJAX", "jQuery", "Social Media API's"];
        var rand = ilovequotes[cnt];
        $('#ilovequote').html(rand);
        $("#ilovequote").fadeIn( 500);
    });
},1000);
```

jsFiddle demo here http://jsfiddle.net/BMBDd/2/

Comment: It is strange using `setTimeout` in `setInterval`

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, I probably just wasn't clear. Thankyou very much!

Answer (score 1):

Remove the extra `});`

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $("#ilovequote").fadeOut(500, function () {
        var ilovequotes = ["CSS3", "Photoshop", "AJAX", "jQuery", "Social Media API's"];
        var rand = ilovequotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * ilovequotes.length)];
        $('#ilovequote').html(rand);
        $("#ilovequote").fadeIn(500);
    });
}, 500);
```

[UPDATE]:

Swap your last two lines in your updated jsfiddle (lines 7 & 8)

http://jsfiddle.net/samliew/rJDWb/2/

Comment: Sorry, that was left over from where I copied it out. That isn't what's breaking it, unfortunately.